# Log Monitoring of Multiple Computers with Get-WinEvent

Tags: powershell, event-log, get-winevent

From the line of code below, is there a way to **call a .txt file for a list of computers** to be looked at? I want it to look for logs in not just one computer but from a list of computers.

```
$StartDate = (get-date).AddHours(-12)
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="System"; Level=1,2,3; starttime=$StartDate} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Hope to hear from you soon! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `-ComputerName` parameter of the `Get-WinEvent` cmdlet does only accept a string, you probably have to iterate over the list:

```
$StartDate = (get-date).AddHours(-12)

Get-Content 'computers.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $_ -FilterHashtable @{logname="System"; Level=1,2,3; starttime=$StartDate} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue    
}
```

Comment: I've tried the one you gave but received the error, `Get-Winevent : The RPC server is unavailable`. Also, it worked on the local machine but not on the other ones on the computers.txt.

Comment: This is probably another topic, just search for the message and you will find ways to solve it.

Comment: Tried using IP addresses instead of computer names and it seems to work fine. Will update this thread once done with futher testing. Thanks, Martin!

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider to accept the answer